# XML Utility class exist for simple modification - add, remove/delete, change/modify?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Does a Java library exist that has the capability shown in the client code below? I'm looking for a library that provides basic XML manipulation capabilities using strings.

```
MagicXml mXml = MagicXmlUtil.createXml("<team name='cougars'><players><player name='Michael'/></players></team>");
mXml.addNode("players", "<player name='Frank'/>");
mXml.addNode("players", "<player name='Delete Me'/>");
mXml.removeNode("player[@name='Delete Me']");
mXml.addAttribute("team[@name='cougars']", "city", "New York");
mXml.addAttribute("team[@name='cougars']", "deleteMeAttribute", "Delete Me");
mXml.removeAttribute("team[@name='cougars']", "deleteMeAttribute");
mXml.modifyAttribute("player[@name='Michael']", "name", "Mike");
mXml.setNodeValue("player[@name='Mike']", "node value for Mike");
MagicXmlNode node = mXml.getNode("<player[@name='Frank'/>");
mXml.addNode("players", node);
mXml.modifyAttribute("player[@name='Frank'][1]", "name", "Frank2");
System.out.println("mXml:\n" + mXml.toString());

mXml:
<team name='cougars' city="New York">
    <players>
        <player name='Mike'>
            node value for Mike
        </player>
        <player name='Frank' />
        <player name='Frank2' />
    </players>
</team>
```

Comment: Just write an utility class around XPath queries, that's all it takes.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid duplicating someone else's code and this seems to me like a group of common functionality that would already have a library. And if it does indeed exist, it would be good for the community to converge on one solution instead of everyone writing their own.

Comment: see my answer for a starting sample.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much; your code works just how I would have hoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you use something already existing like dom4j or jdom or as I said in my comment you create a simple class that wraps call to finding nodes using XPath and adding/removing what you want (Nodes, Attributes etc).

This is a sample class, I'll let you add what's missing (`modifyAttribute`, `setNodeValue` etc)

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class MagicXml {
    static XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Document doc;
    Element root;

    public MagicXml(String xml) throws Exception {
        doc = parseXml(xml);
        root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    }

    private static Document parseXml(String xml) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
        return docBuilder.parse(bis);
    }

    private String asXPath(String path) {
        return path.startsWith("/") ? path : "//" + path;
    }

    private static Node findNode(Document doc, String xPath) throws Exception {
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xPath);
        return (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    }

    public static MagicXml createXml(String xml) throws Exception {
        return new MagicXml(xml);
    }

    public MagicXml addNode(String path, String xml) throws Exception {
        Document subDoc = parseXml(xml);
        Node destNode = findNode(doc, asXPath(path));
        Node srcNode = subDoc.getFirstChild();
        destNode.appendChild(doc.adoptNode(srcNode.cloneNode(true)));
        return this;
    }

    public MagicXml removeNode(String path) throws Exception {
        Node destNode = findNode(doc, asXPath(path));
        destNode.getParentNode().removeChild(destNode);
        return this;
    }

    public MagicXml addAttribute(String path, String attr, String value) throws Exception {
        Element destNode = (Element)findNode(doc, asXPath(path));
        destNode.setAttribute(attr, value);
        return this;
    }

    public MagicXml removeAttribute(String path, String attr) throws Exception {
        Element destNode = (Element)findNode(doc, asXPath(path));
        destNode.removeAttribute(attr);
        return this;
    }

    public String docToString(Document doc) {
        try {
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
            return sw.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return docToString(doc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(//
                MagicXml.createXml("<team name='cougars'><players><player name='Michael'/></players></team>")//
                .addNode("players", "<player name='Frank'/>")//
                .addNode("players", "<player name='Delete Me'/>")//
                .removeNode("player[@name='Delete Me']") //
                .addAttribute("player[@name='Frank']", "foo", "bar") //
                .addAttribute("player[@name='Frank']", "bar", "bazz") //
                .removeAttribute("player[@name='Frank']", "bar") //
                .toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I added setNodeValue and your addAttribute is essentially modifyAttribute. Just need to get this in a repository, but you are right, it is pretty simple once you know the basic concepts.
 
`public MagicXml setNodeValue(String path, String value) throws      Exception {
     Node destNode = (Node)findNode(doc, asXPath(path));
        destNode.setTextContent(value);
        return this;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

there are many different java libraries for xml manipulation/editing, the basics one with java standard library are hard to use if your a beginner so you should try JDOM(java document object model) for parsing and editing is easy.
Read a bit of documentation and download sample code here if you want to try http://www.jdom.org/ good luck =)

Comment: There are many different java xml libraries, but none seem to have the capability or simplicity of the hypothetical MagicXmlUtil class. If MagicXmlUtil is impossible to implement or is compromising robustness then I might consider something else, but I just don't see how that is the case.

Answer (score -1):

XStream is a very easy XML manipulation tool.  It can go from java classes to XML and vice versa very easily.

Comment: I don't want to have to create a java class; the XML needs to be dynamic.